# How to create Azure Container SAS Token signed with Account key with PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage

I need to create a SAS token for a container using PowerShell with an expiry date one year from now. If I use `New-AzStorageContainerSASToken` I cannot set an expiry date after 7 days because it uses a user delegation key.

For example, if I do this:

```
$container = New-AzStorageContainer -Name $saName -Context $backupContext
$token = $container | New-AzStorageContainerSASToken -Permission rwdl -ExpiryTime (Get-Date).AddYears(1)
```

I get error

```
New-AzStorageContainerSASToken: Generate User Delegation SAS with OAuth bases Storage context. User Delegate Key expiry time 20/07/2023 15:46:12 +00:00 must be in 7 days from now.
```

How can I specify to sign with the account key instead?

Comment: Do you have access to account key? Or have permissions to get the account key?

Comment: @GauravMantri yes I do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the account name and key, you can create a context using that. You can then pass that context to `New-AzStorageContainerSASToken` Cmdlet.

Something like:

```
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "account-name" -StorageAccountKey "account-key"
$container = New-AzStorageContainer -Name $saName -Context $ctx
$token = $container | New-AzStorageContainerSASToken -Permission rwdl -ExpiryTime (Get-Date).AddYears(1) -Context $ctx
```

You can learn more about New-AzStorageContext here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstoragecontext?view=azps-8.1.0.